# Converting Word Document with PDFTron(Convert.ToPdf) gives error "Failed to obtain dispatch handle to opened document"

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, pdftron

I have office standard 2016 with valid license installed on windows server 2016(64 bit) and PdfTron(32 bit)  i am trying to convert word document to pdf via PdfTron and it's virtual printer with Convert.ToPdf() method with below code

```
try
            {
                string conversionPath = string.Empty;
                using (pdftron.PDF.PDFDoc pdfdoc = new pdftron.PDF.PDFDoc())
                {
                    if (pdftron.PDF.Convert.RequiresPrinter(sourceFilePath))
                    {
                        if (pdftron.PDF.Convert.Printer.IsInstalled("PDFTron PDFNet"))
                        {
                            pdftron.PDF.Convert.Printer.SetPrinterName("PDFTron PDFNet");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            pdftron.PDF.Convert.Printer.Install();
                            pdftron.PDF.Convert.Printer.SetPrinterName("PDFTron PDFNet");
                        }
                    }
                    conversionPath = System.IO.Path.ChangeExtension(sourceFilePath, ".pdf");
                    pdftron.PDF.Convert.ToPdf(pdfdoc, sourceFilePath);
                    pdfdoc.Save(conversionPath, pdftron.SDF.SDFDoc.SaveOptions.e_linearized);
                    System.IO.File.Delete(sourceFilePath);
                }
                return conversionPath;
            }
            catch (pdftron.Common.PDFNetException ex)
            {
                return string.Empty;
            }
        }
```

when i try to do so it gives me below error.

```
    Exception: 
     Message: An error occurred while converting the file.
Detailed error:
    Exception: 
     Message: Failed to obtain dispatch handle to opened document.
      File: "Word.cpp":646
    Log:
      Start check system account.
      Session ID is: 0.
      Done checking system account.
      Start checking registry.
      Registry check done.
      Creating a Word application instance.
      Word application instance created.
      Application.AutomationSecurity ID obtained.
      Application.AutomationSecurity value set to 3.
      Application.DisplayAlerts ID obtained.
      Application.Version ID obtained.
      Application version: 16.
      Application.Build ID obtained.
      Application build: 16.0.4266.
      Application.Documents ID obtained.
      Opening document "XXXXXX".
      Documents.Open ID obtained.

     Conditional expression: FALSE
     Version    : 6.8.7.67376
     Filename   : Convert.cpp
     Function   : trn::PDF::Convert::ToPDFViaOffice
     Linenumber : 1788

Failed to obtain dispatch handle to opened document.
      File: "Word.cpp":646
    Log:
      Start check system account.
      Session ID is: 0.
      Done checking system account.
      Start checking registry.
      Registry check done.
      Creating a Word application instance.
      Word application instance created.
      Application.AutomationSecurity ID obtained.
      Application.AutomationSecurity value set to 3.
      Application.DisplayAlerts ID obtained.
      Application.Version ID obtained.
      Application version: 16.
      Application.Build ID obtained.
      Application build: 16.0.4266.
      Application.Documents ID obtained.
      Opening document "XXXXXXX".
      Documents.Open ID obtained.

     Conditional expression: false
     Version    : 6.8.7.67376
     Filename   : Convert.cpp
     Function   : trn::PDF::Convert::ToPdf
     Linenumber : 1734
```

I am not quite sure what this means since PDFTron and office both have valid license keys, any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: Does this occur with any Word document or only certain ones? How are you running the process; command line? service? What about Powerpoint or Excel documents, do they convert? Is MS Word licensed, or are you running it in evaluation mode?

Comment: You are probably running this from a service context. This is not strictly supported (see [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office)).

Comment: @Ryan None of Excel or Powerpoint documents working, i am trying to convert this via C# code, https://www.pdftron.com/api/PDFNet/html/Overload_pdftron_PDF_Convert_ToPdf.htm

Comment: You did not clarify how you are running your process, but I assume either as a service, or IIS web worker. Please try this test project. www.pdftron.com/ID-zJWLuhTffd3c/support//PDFNet_IIS_Word_ToXod_Test2013.7z

Comment: @Ryan sorry it's IIS web worked i will give it a try to your link

Comment: Great, please let me know how the PDFNet_IIS_Word_ToXod_Test works.

Comment: @Ryan I see you have used .ToXod method which works fine for me as well, but issue is when i use printer with https://www.pdftron.com/api/PDFNet/html/M_pdftron_PDF_Convert_ToPdf_4.htm method to convert office document to PDF at that point i am getting posted error

Comment: You can change the test project to call ToXo. Internally ToXod will call ToPdf anyway. If that doesn't help, please update your question to reflect what you tested and the results. Thanks

Comment: @Ryan I have updated my question with code i am trying and added some more detail, hope it will help

Comment: The "Failed to obtain dispatch handle to opened document." message does not occur for Powerpoint or Excel, so those must have a different error message? What are those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I would recommend relaxing the account credentials as much as possible, making them as close to a standard user as possible. Once you have conversion working correctly, you can begin restricting.

The following are the main checklist that you should ensure work.

1. MS Word is licensed/activated, especially for the account being used.
   We recommend you create a Windows Service and run the conversion in a separate process. Then run the service as a user who is an administrator and has rights to run the service. Also the user who is running the service has to have accepted the MS office licensing to make sure Office is a fully licensed product.
2. Make sure the Print Spool service is running. For many Windows versions, you can enable the print spooler by running the following at a command line: `net start spooler`
3. Make sure the account running the conversion has access to a desktop folder. Local System, or Local Service’s, desktop folders can be found in the following locations:
   `C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\Desktop`
   `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\Desktop` (only on 64-bit Windows)
   These folder(s) need to exist, and your account being used needs to have read/write access to them.

Comment: seems like point no. 3 did the trick can you please explain why it is needed ?

Comment: Ok great. When using Microsoft Office, before the application actually opens, the desktop folder of the user must be present. For example, when user “Bob” opens Microsoft Office Excel, Excel requires the folder “C:\Users\Bob\Desktop” to be both present and accessible. Similarly, for Windows Service, Excel expects “LOCAL SYSTEM’s” or “LOCAL SERVICE’s” desktop folder to be present and accessible before the process will continue.